# C# simple Powershell script returns error: System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I have a simple script that runs when a windows form loads.  It gets the user's login name, which is necessary for other features in the app.  The app works fine other than this one part.   On my development machine I have no problems at all and the command runs just fine.  However, when I run the app in test machine it throws an error show below.

I am not a powershell user and have very little experience with it, but I don't believe I am even using a snap in.  Can anyone help me alleviate this error?

> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException: Cannot load
>   Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics because of
>   the following error: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.LoadMshSnapinAssembly(PSSnapInInfo
>   mshsnapinInfo)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.LoadPSSnapIn(PSSnapInInfo
>   mshsnapinInfo)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.LoadPSSnapIns(Collection`1
>   mshsnapinInfos, PSConsoleLoadException& warning)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.CreateDefaultConfiguration()
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(PSHost
>   host)    at HPSM_Assistant.HPSMAssistant.ADuser() in
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\HPSMAssistant\HPSMAssistant\Form1.cs:line
>   592    at HPSM_Assistant.HPSMAssistant.LoadTemplateEID() in
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\HPSMAssistant\HPSMAssistant\Form1.cs:line
>   396    at HPSM_Assistant.HPSMAssistant.Form1_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\HPSMAssistant\HPSMAssistant\Form1.cs:line
>   208    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Also System.Management.Automation - Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0 -Win32 Version: 10.0.10586.0 loads correctly. (It was installed in the c# app via Nuget.)

Here is the code I use:

```
  private string ADuser()// create Powershell runspace and run script to Get AD current username
    {

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
        scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser");
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$env:UserName");
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
        //Create string to output
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: Is powershell installed and are you able to run powershell command from powershell command prompt?

Comment: Yes PowerShell is installed. I can run env:UserName successfully on the machine.

Comment: What version of PS do you have installed on the test machine? Run '$PSVersionTable' in a PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Both Machines have the same version (installed through corporate software store)PSVersion                      3.0                                                                                                                                                                                         
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}

Comment: Hi, did you try to run [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4) so you could identify any assembly that failed loading? 
In addition you could check yor `$env:PSModulePath` variable as it is seen by your application to ensure it points at the right direction.